# Error when running jekyll in Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: ruby, linux, jekyll, linux-mint

I just set up Jekyll on my Linux machine and installed (I think) all the necessary dependencies. When I try to run `jekyll serve` or `jekyll build`, I get the error displayed below. However, if I run `jekyll new "test"` to create a new site, it works just fine.

Here is the error message I am receiving (it's the exact same for `serve` and `build`):

```
Configuration file: /home/michael/Dev/github-site/_config.yml
/home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-sitemap (LoadError)
from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:29:in `block in require_gems'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `each'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `require_gems'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:79:in `setup'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `initialize'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `new'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to using Jekyll and Ruby.

Comment: Just a guess, but if the "test" works fine, then maybe there's a problem with your config/files? And tried a web search for the first error, "kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-sitemap (LoadError)" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do a :

```
gem install jekyll-sitemap
```